# Brace { } navigation without opening folds

Tags: key-bindings, folding, navigation

I use `{`/`}` a lot for navigating around, but when I do this I **never** intend to open a fold and jump to blank lines *within* the fold.

How can I `nremap` `{` and `}` to skip over folds?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Thanks to @romainl for [this answer on super user](https://superuser.com/a/836920/359608). I couldn't have written this without their help!*

---

You can use the `foldopen` option to determine which set of motions will or won't open a fold. From `:h 'foldopen'`

```
                        *'foldopen'* *'fdo'*
'foldopen' 'fdo'    string (default: "block,hor,mark,percent,quickfix,
                                 search,tag,undo")
            global
            {not in Vi}
            {not available when compiled without the |+folding|
            feature}
    Specifies for which type of commands folds will be opened, if the
    command moves the cursor into a closed fold.  It is a comma separated
    list of items.
    NOTE: When the command is part of a mapping this option is not used.
    Add the |zv| command to the mapping to get the same effect.
    (rationale: the mapping may want to control opening folds itself)
```

As for which values are allowed, and which commands they affect, refer to this table:

```
item        commands ~
all         any
block       "(", "{", "[[", "[{", etc.
hor         horizontal movements: "l", "w", "fx", etc.
insert      any command in Insert mode
jump        far jumps: "G", "gg", etc.
mark        jumping to a mark: "'m", CTRL-O, etc.
percent     "%"
quickfix    ":cn", ":crew", ":make", etc.
search      search for a pattern: "/", "n", "*", "gd", etc.
                (not for a search pattern in a ":" command)
                Also for |[s| and |]s|.
tag         jumping to a tag: ":ta", CTRL-T, etc.
undo        undo or redo: "u" and CTRL-R
```

As you can see, the `{` and `}` motions are in `block`, so if you run:

```
:set foldopen-=block
```

that should fix it for you.